# Не запускается Activity

Tags: java, android, activity, android-manifest

Подскажите, почему может не запускаться активити? Стектрейс грешит на манифест:

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit
>   activity class
>   {com.iam.oneohm/com.iam.oneohm.widget.EpisodeInfoWindow}; have you
>   declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml? at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1541)
>   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1416)
>   at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3351) at
>   android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3312) at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:784)
>   at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3522) at
>   android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3490) at
>   com.iam.oneohm.pages.main.MainPageActivity$EpisodesAdapter$EpisodeVH$1.onClick(MainPageActivity.java:160)
>   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084) at
>   android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966) at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615) at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

НО в манифесте активити объявлена:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.iam">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" android:name=".pages.main.MainPageActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity  android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" android:name=".pages.main.EpisodeWindowActivity" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Вызов происходит так

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), EpisodeInfoWindow.class);
intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.episode_page_intent), ep);
startActivity(intent);
```

Я что то делаю не так?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы всё таки не объявили активити в манифесте и компилятор всё верно вам сказал. Вы пытаетесь открыть `EpisodeInfoWindow`, а в манифесте есть только `MainPageActivity` и `EpisodeWindowActivity`

Comment: Вот оно недосыпание) Спасибо

Comment: @iamthevoid, если ответ решил вашу проблему, то вы можете проголосовать за него и отметить его верным)

Answer (score 2):

Вместо того, что бы создавать файлы в ручную, а потом прописывать их в разных файлах, используйте встроенную функцию.
Нажми на layout в ресурсах ПКМ и тогда NEW>Activity>Empty Activity, тогда все заработает. Удачи)

Comment: Спасибо, я по старинке))